# How to extract a JSON object depending on symbol?

Tags: json, react-native

I have this JSON.stringify object (not an array),

```
  "city": "Tokyo,Japan,Asia",
```

which can be like this too :

```
"city": "London"
```

I want to extract only the first item if there is a coma, and everything if there isn't a coma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) property to achieve this

```
const city1 = "Tokyo,Japan,Asia"

const city2 = "London"

city1.split(',')[0]
city2.split(',')[0]
```